# Dompdf split table into half of the page

Tags: html, html-table, dompdf

i want to generate an html table to generate to pdf from dompdf, the problem is i need to split the table into two like this when there is too much row record on table that causing the page to break:

[image: table example]

Comment: What is the question? What do you have already? What have you tried?

Comment: @Qwertie i need to split the record like the above image if the table row record is overlapping the table height